# React Native Android: Component names stripped in production?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm hitting some JavaScript runtime issues in production on my React Native Android app, but I'm having a hard time debugging them because the component names are being re-named to random letters (and in some instances "Unknown") in production:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.profileType.toLowerCase')
This error is located at:
in t
in InjectIntl(t)
in Apollo(InjectIntl(t))
in Apollo(Apollo(InjectIntl(t)))
in Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(InjectIntl(t))))
in Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(InjectIntl(t)))))
in Connect(Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(Apollo(InjectIntl(t))))))
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in t
in n
```

Is there a way I can preserve my class / component names so I can track down these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of an Android tool called Proguard.

It obfuscates classes in release builds so it's harder for hackers to figure out what a class does, and how to exploit it.

There's 2 things you can do:
1) Disable Proguard completely on release builds.
2) Setup correct "Proguard rules" which tells Proguard what classes to not obfuscate, but still obfuscates the rest.

Nr 1 is by far the easiest, and just google "disable proguard react native" or so, and you'll find answers.
Nr 2 is by far the best option. This way you still protect most of the code, and only allow certain elements to not be obfuscated (so it still works). Though this also takes more work, and a bit of knowledge about how Proguard works. If you want to go down this round, try googling "proguard rules javascript react native" or so, and you can find some help.